# How to update chef cookbooks in a developer workflow

Tags: chef-infra

I'm managing a chef server and I want to pull the latest cookbooks (if they have been changed, or new ones added). This is so that I can develop on the newest changes, and be sure I'm not working with stale data. I would assume it would be similar to git workflow where I pull the latest and merge if necessary.

I know I can issue a "knife download /" but this seems costly and time-consuming, to download the entire repo each time.

Oddly enough - I haven't been able to find any articles or documentation that suggest how to do this. Which makes me think, possibly my workflow is not correct or I am missing a larger piece.

Is there a better way to update my repo, and get into quick, efficient developer workflow?

Comment: Your cookbooks need to be in Git, of course! The produced artifact (the cookbook) should then be automatically upload to the Chef server. Here's what I/we do: [An Open Source Chef Cookbook CI/CD Implementation Using Jenkins Pipelines](https://www.slideshare.net/StephenKing/an-opensource-chef-cookbook-cicd-implementation-using-jenkins-pipelines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookbooks, and all Chef data other than nodes and clients, is generally kept in git. Chef Server handles releases of that data, but not development.

Answer (score 0):

Configure berkshelf to fetch your cookbooks from the desired git repository
https://docs.chef.io/berkshelf.html

Comment: Add as many details as you can to give good insight to the question. This answer may be correct but it will be invalid if the referenced url doesn't work. This has been flagged in reviews.