# How to stage, develop, and test changes to the chef repo

Tags: chef-infra

I wanted to ask what the best practice, and what is commonly done for testing and developing changes to cookbooks,environments,nodes, essentially the chef repo. Reason I ask this, is the current setup has one chef server. All environments (staging, beta, prod) use this server and have all the relevant info pulled from here.

However, when I want to make a change to a cookbook and test it on one of our staging environments...it pulls from this repo and I either have to make a mess of configuration changes or...upload a cookbook with a different name, test, and then proceed to rename my cookbook back to the original name. Far from efficient, and frustrating even.

I thought maybe I could have different git branches and somehow point them in different directions but it would still be pulling from the same repo I imagine..

My thought then was to simply have an entirely separate chef server dedicated for developing and testing, and point my staging environments to that chef server.

Not sure if there was another more simple way I was missing, thus why I'm asking the community.

This may seem related to another question I asked, but I hope the difference between these two questions is clear ([How to update chef cookbooks in a developer workflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727013/how-to-update-chef-cookbooks-in-a-developer-workflow))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Stefan, environments are one option here. You can also look at the environment cookbook pattern (which is similar but uses a different workflow to update the environment and manage run lists, or the newer Policyfile system. I would recommend starting with Policyfiles if you can, though they have some limitations and may not work for all teams.

Comment: This idea works because I specify an environment to use the latest cookbook version (cookbook_version in environment file) and upload my in-development files, and at the same time specify a version of the same cookbook in the production environment file (through the same cookbook_version attribute). since the prod environment won't pick the latest, and the test env will, there will be no issue. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: Yes, but as I said, you should probably start with Policyfiles instead.

Comment: same question but diff area - We use a bit of AWS opsworks in our stack, although I didn't find anything saying that I could version and pin cookbooks or any examples explicitly using policyfiles. Is that not available in opsworks?

Comment: Correct, OpsWorks Stacks is unrelated to normal Chef for all workflow tasks. You'll have to take that up with them, we have no input or control.

Answer (score 1):

Chef has the notion of different environments: https://docs.chef.io/environments.html

You can have prod and staging environment files which have all relevant cookbooks pinned to a stable version.

Then when you make a change to your cookbook you should bump the version number and update the staging environment with the new version so you can test the changes there. I.e.

```
chef exec knife environment from file environments/staging.json
```

And then only update the prod environment with the new version when you've tested the changes and are happy with them.